# How to write an Oracle trigger based on Auto incremented value?

Tags: oracle, triggers, auto-increment

I have an Oracle Table with the following keys: ID, Name, DoB, Dept & FileNo. The ID field is the primary Key with an Auto Incremented value.

I wish to write a trigger, so that when a row is added with the Name, DoB & Dept , the FileNo field should get the value yyyy/xxxx where 'yyyy' is a predefined string  & 'xxxx' is the value in ID field.

How do I do this?

Comment: Perhaps you need a simple view or a materialized view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a sequence to implement an Auto Incremented value:

```
create sequence seq_file_id start with 1 increment by 1;
```

and a trigger on a table

```
CREATE TRIGGER file_trg 
   BEFORE insert 
   ON file_table 
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
      SELECT seq_file_id.NEXTVAL INTO :new.id FROM dual;
      :NEW.fileno := 'yyyy' || :new.id;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

If it will always be the ID with some prefix, then it probably shouldn't be a column. If that is the default, then a trigger that sets `:new.fileno := 'string'||:new.id` should suffice.

Oracle doesn't have auto increment, so you probably mean a sequence. If you have a trigger populating that, then this can go in the same trigger.